# Htaccess with Magento; Rewrite rule creates display issues

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

We just put a website online, using a default htaccess with Magento and adding a few rewrite rules to move old URLs. Sadly, after multiples hours, we can't make it right.

website: http://www.lebernard.ca

Here is the htaccess: http://pastebin.com/aKc78qDW

We try to add the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^chiens/shih-tzu/$ /chiens/races/shih-tzu/ [L,R=301]
```

When we put it online, it generates a 404 on some images, either called from wyziwig or css.

Do you have any idea why it would do so?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please include your source code in the question. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry Makyen, I've used Pastebin because with all embedded comments and such, the htaccess rendered horribly on stackoverflow.

Comment: Are your image links relative URLs?

Comment: They are all absolute URLs.

Comment: Where can we see an example of the problem?

Comment: Hi bobdye! I've uploaded the rewrite rule so you can see the problem. Go on the website http://www.lebernard.ca, you'll see that some icons do not work. EX: social networks at the bottom, the brown square at bottom right should also be an icon)